# Duplicate row in a table after insert

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a block of code that imports data from a text file to a table in Access. Each row in the text file should be saved separately in the table, but sometimes I have a duplicate row in the table. For example I have a text file like this:

```
Water
Bird
Summer
```

Sometimes and NOT always I see two `Summer` in the table. Always the last row of the text file is duplicated.

here is my VB code:

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()
    Dim ifile As Integer
    Dim db As Database
    Dim name As String

    Let ifile = FreeFile
    name = util1.fDateiName("*.lab", "Lable")
    Me.RecordSource = ""
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tb_lable_Daten")
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT name FROM tb_lable_Daten"

   If name <> "" Then
       Open name For Input As ifile
       While Not EOF(ifile)
           Line Input #ifile, entireline
           'MsgBox entireline
           DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_lable_Daten (name) VALUES ('" & entireline & "');")
       Wend
       List5.Requery
       List5.SetFocus

       MsgBox ("Die Daten sind erfolgreich gespeichert")
   End If
End Sub
```

How can I solve this problem? and why does this problem occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my view it seems somehow the file is processing beyond the last
>   line (which is summer in this case). Since you are not initializing
>   the varaible i:e entireline during each iteration so for the messed up
>   case its taking the last valid input (summer in your case). Try to
>   check and insert if and only if you have a valid value in entireline 
>   variable and then re-initialize the entireline variable to blank after insertion. I hope this will solve the issue.